# If Statements based on selection from dropdown

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, dropdown

I have read through all of the other articles and I am not finding my answers.

I start out with a JOptionPane with object options.  When the user selects either animals or habitat another drop down will appears with selections.  Right now I am working on getting another pop up with information to open when Lions is selected.  But I can't get it to work.

Also I viewed someone else's input to have the ability for these drop downs to appear.  But they are using JFrame so another window for java opens up outside of NetBeans.

What I am trying to do right now is enter if statements for selections from dropdown but I don't think it is working correctly.  When I run the code and select animals and choose Tigers the window for Lions will pop up and when I say okay the Tigers box pops up.  I also need to figure out how to enter a warning statement in some of the selections from dropdown.  For health concerns for each animal.  I thought about adding a button for additional information but I want to be able to have it automatically pop up.  I'm still reading through the API documentation but I just want a simple message dialog to display the information.

```
   public class MonitoringSystem {

   public static void main(String[] args){




ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img.class.getResource("zoo.png"));
    String[] options = {"Animals", "Habitat", "Exit"};
    int x = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Zookeepers would you like     to view animal activities or monitor habitats?",
            "Welcome to the Brooklyn Zoo!",     JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, icon, options,     options[0]);
System.out.println(x);  


JFrame animal = new JFrame("Animals");  


JFrame habitat = new JFrame("Habitats"); 

if(x==0){  
animal.setVisible(true); 
String[] choices = {"Lions","Tigers","Bears","Giraffes",};
String input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Select Animal:","Zoo     Animals",
JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,choices,choices[1]);




if ("Lions".equals(choices));
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Animal: Lion\nName: Leo\nAge: 5    \nFeeding Schedule: Twice daily");
{

}
if("Tigers".equals(choices));
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Animal: Tiger\nName: Maj\nAge: 15    \nFeeding Schedule: 3x daily");
```

Comment: You are thinking of `\n` to add a newline character, not `/n`. Also, you cannot compare strings using ==, please use `String#equals()`.

Comment: I tried using if String.equals("Lions") but I'm getting an error.

Comment: String is a class and the equals method is not a static method. In your situation, this would mean you should do `"Lions".equals(choice)`.

Comment: When I type if ("Lions".equals.(choice)); its giving me an unclosed string literal.

Comment: There shouldn't be a `.` after `equals`.

Comment: I don't have a period after it.  It now reads if ("Lions".equals(choices));

Comment: You can't have a semicolon after an if statement. So your code should be <br>`if ("Lions".equals(choices)) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Animal: Lion\nName: Leo\nAge: 5    \nFeeding Schedule: Twice daily");}`

Answer (score 1):

```
if(choice=="Lions")
```

Don't use "==" for Object comparison.

Instead use the `String.equals(...)` method.

> I start out with a JOptionPane with object options

Sound reasonable. You create an Array of String options and use the `showOptionPane(...)` method.

> Right now I am working on getting another pop up with information to open when Lions is selected

So why are you using `showInputDialog(...)` this time?

If `showOptionPane(...)` worked before why are you changing methods?

```
JFrame animal = new JFrame("Animals");  
JFrame habitat = new JFrame("Habitats");
```

What is the point of those statements?

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more examples of using a JOptionPane.

If you are just trying to display information about a Lion. then add the text to a JTextArea and then display the JTextArea in the JOptionPane. You can add any Swing component to an JOptionPane. Read the JOptionPane API.

Comment: When I remove JFrame animal = new JFrame("Animals");  
 

JFrame habitat = new JFrame("Habitats"); when I select Animals or Habitat or Cancel from the box it does nothing

Comment: I figured this out.  Thanks for the help!